# longitudinal models for prevalence

Tags: binomial-distribution, panel-data, cluster-sample

I am trying to analyze some prevalence data and estimate the effect on prevalence of some health condition of an intervention that was introduced at some time point. The data concern a number of clusters and I have summary data (number of diseased and cluster sizes) for each cluster, at each discrete time point. The intervention was not introduced at the same time point for each cluster. So the data I have are of the form $x_{ij}, N_i, I_{ij}$, denoting for cluster $i$ and time point $j$ the number of diseased people, total size of cluster (i.e. diseased plus non diseased) and indicator variable for the presence/absence of intervention.

What is needed is estimation of the effect of the intervention on the prevalence of disease.

Any suggestions on models relevant for this problem would be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Are these clusters randomized to receive the intervention or not? If not, do you have data on confounders, and at what level (individuals or clusters)? In either case, is there any possibility of spatial heterogeneity in disease prevalence, either through interference between clusters or via unmeasured neighborhood characteristics? How you analyze the data will depend on at least these three issues.

Comment: Thanks @AzulaR. Every cluster will receive the intervention at some point, the time is random. We expect to have heterogeneity in both control prevalence and the effect of the intervention. We do not have any information about confounding factors at this point. Also, there is no spatial correlation between clusters (is that what you meant?) The only correlation is between time points. Any suggestion would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, one last question, I think. Are you wanting to compare clusters with interventions to themselves at a time point when they did not have the intervention, or compare clusters with interventions now to clusters without interventions now?

Comment: @AzulaR., the question is whether intervention has an effect on the prevalence. I guess from the two ways you mentioned the first one seems more relevant.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have a set of clusters and are assigning each cluster to receive the intervention at a random time point, and assessing whether receipt of the intervention changes the disease prevalence in the cluster.

So, you want to know either the prevalence difference E[Y|intervention=1] - E[Y|intervention=0] or the prevalence ratio E[Y|intervention=1]/E[Y|intervention=0]. Where Y = prevalence = $x_{ij}/N_{i}$.

If you think the intervention has a single unique effect in each cluster (time-invariant effect), then you should probably just be calculating those from your data. You may get bias if you have within-cluster time-varying confounding, in any given cluster - ex. other reasons the prevalence of disease naturally changes over time. So you may want to consider measuring any important confounders of that type.

If you believe instead that there is a single time-invariant effect of the intervention on average over all the clusters, and wanted to adjust for the fact that clusters are matched to themselves, you could analyze this like a crossover study and run a conditional logistic regression $clogit(Y) = \beta_{0,i} +\beta_1I_{i,j}$. However, you will once again have to worry about bias if there are time-varying confounders within the clusters. You can adjust for this by including these variables in the regression model. This gives you the prevalence odds, but since you have a longitudinal study, you should be able to validly convert that back to the prevalence by taking the expit.

If you think the effect varies over time, then I'm not sure what the best approach is.

Comment: Hello @AzulaR. some other information, in case I missed it, I only have a dozen of "clusters" and each one's size is about about 150-200. Also, I only have the "summary" data (i.e. per cluster) not the actual individual patient data. I looked at clogit function in R, I don't think it is suitable for the model you describe. Any further suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It sounded like you have data on the clusters at multiple time points, which is why I suggested clogit. You could also try generalized additive models (GAM).